# Iterate through and print the keys of a dictionary instead of its values?

Tags: python

I have a series of extremely long URLs with keys in the format of `myurls21,1`, `myurls21,2`, etc. that I am breaking up into component parts using the following statement:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import json


myurls2 = {}
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        strvar1 = "%s" % (x)
        strvar2 = "%s" % (y)

        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y),"r") as f:
            myurls2[x,y] = f.read().replace('\n', '')
            #print("myurls_" + str(strvar1) + "_" + str(strvar2) + "=", myurls2[x,y])
            #print(myurls2[x,y])

URLS = myurls2.values()

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    return conn.readall()


# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}

    c = 0


    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]



        a = ''
        b = ''
        c += 1


        for url in URLS:
            a = url.rsplit("=", 1)[-1]
            print(myurls2.keys())
```

How can I print the key of each URL being split into the log? I have tried `print(myurls2.keys())`, but that prints all of the keys stored within the dictionary (URLS is defined from the contents of the `myurls2` dictionary).

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What kind of object is `URLS`, and what kinds of objects are inside it?

Comment: It is a URL generated from the contents of a text file then submitted to the web using the concurrent.futures module for parallel processing.

Comment: What do you mean by "the key of each URL"? How is URLS defined? What are the keys?

Comment: Saying "it is a URL" isn't getting at what I'm asking.  What kind of Python object is it?  Is it a string?  If so, what do you mean by it having "keys"?

Comment: We need some more code.  What is `myurls2` ?

Comment: a dictionary is created by parsing the values contained within several text files. those values equate to URLs which are then referenced later in the code. the values of the URLs represent the values of the dictionary. the URLs are very long but the keys are quite short and take the format of myurls21,1 etc...I want to print through those as the above code iterates through each dictionary item and subsets the URL strings for something.

Comment: ive edited the post to include more code.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with `myurls2.keys()`.  You say "that prints all of the keys stored within the dictionary", which seems to be exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: If you want access to the keys one at a time, why are you iterating over the values?  Just iterate over the entire dict, as shown in `jonrsharpe`'s answer.

Comment: @BrenBarn im asking for each url that is being parsed that the key of the dictionary for that particular entry is printed at the same time. please see my answer response where i have moved where a is printed.

Comment: @BrenBarn if you add 'q = myurls2.keys()
        print(q)' to the code i answered with it prints out every dictionary key rather than the one for the specific URL being parsed each time.

Comment: @user3045351 I have update my answer; does that cover what you are trying to do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe im not sure how to amend my code to reflect your suggestion as I am quite new to Python. In my code answer I want the key of the url being parsed to be printed where a is being printed. could you show me exactly what syntax to use for that section of code please?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ive borrowed a lot of this code so i'm not 100% on how it works

Comment: @user3045351 ...I have shown you exactly what syntax to use. And I know you've borrowed it, mostly from a trail of similar questions!

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok ive got that to work now. sorry, its getting late and my head is going a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the keys *and* values in a dictionary, you can do for example:

```
for key, url in myurls2.items():
    print(key)
    a = url.rsplit("=", 1)[-1]
```

---

If you want the keys for the urls you have passed to `concurrent`, refactor to allow this:

```
future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): (key, url)
                 for key, url in myurls2.items()}
```

Now you can access it:

```
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
    key, url = future_to_url[future]
    # print key and process url
```